# Trying to select all records where two fields are distinct (but the rest don't have to be)

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has 14 columns in it.  These columns are color, type, ft, date, count, etc.  What I need is to select all distinct records of id and type with the most recent date.  So, for example...

color------type-----------date

red--------work-----------01/01/01

red---------play----------02/02/02

red---------play----------03/03/03

In this case, I want to return red, work, 01/01/01 and red, play 03/03/03.    Hopefully this makes sense.  I've tried different combinations of select unique and select distinct and group bys, and I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Here is the SQL statement I'm trying:

```
select distinct
  chock_id, 
  roll_type, 
  max(chock_service_dt), 
  chock_id_dt, 
  chock_seq_num, 
  chock_service_cmnt, 
  total_rolled_lineal_ft, 
  total_rolled_tons, 
  chock_usage_cnt, 
  chock_insert_dt, 
  record_modify_dt, 
  next_chock_service_dt_act,
  previous_alarm_value, 
  upload_complete_yn 
from 
  tp07_chock_summary_row 
group by 
  chock_id, 
  roll_type,
  chock_service_dt, 
  chock_id_dt, 
  chock_seq_num, 
  chock_service_cmnt, 
  total_rolled_lineal_ft, 
  total_rolled_tons, 
  chock_usage_cnt, 
  chock_insert_dt, 
  record_modify_dt, 
  next_chock_service_dt_act,
  previous_alarm_value, 
  upload_complete_yn;
```

[image]

Here's a screenshot.  Like I said in a comment below, like in rows 2 and 4, I can't have multiple records with the same chock_id and roll_type.

Comment: So, out of all `chock_seq_num` (and other columns) for a particular combination of `chock_id` and `roll_type`, which one do you want?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understand the question.  I posted a screenshot in the OP.  See how rows 2 and 4 are both blue/work?  I can't have that.  I can only have one green/work, blue/work, etc.

Comment: So for the combination of "green" and "work" you have several different values in the column `chock_seq_num` (and I might assume in other columns as well). Since you want only one row in the output with "green" and "work", which of the many possible values of `chock_seq_num` do you expect to see?

Comment: I just want the record with the most recent chock_service_dt.  Basically, it's a piece of hardware that gets replaced on the chock_service_dt, so all of the older data is unnecessary.  I only want the most recent date for each combo of chock_id and roll_type.

Comment: So, there should only be like 9 rows.  There should be black/work, blue backup, blue work, green backup, green work, grey backup, red work, white work, and yellow work.  But i need the one with the most recent date, as well as all the rest of the data from their respective columns.

So, I'm expecting to have 9 records, each with 14 columns of data.  And it should be the most recent chock_service_dt

Comment: Please see my another answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your new requirements, which you did not explain initially, this should do it:

```
  select 
    chock_id, 
    roll_type, 
    chock_service_dt,
    chock_id_dt, 
    chock_seq_num, 
    chock_service_cmnt, 
    total_rolled_lineal_ft, 
    total_rolled_tons, 
    chock_usage_cnt, 
    chock_insert_dt, 
    record_modify_dt, 
    next_chock_service_dt_act,
    previous_alarm_value, 
    upload_complete_yn 
  from (
     select 
       chock_id, 
       roll_type, 
       chock_service_dt,
       chock_id_dt, 
       chock_seq_num, 
       chock_service_cmnt, 
       total_rolled_lineal_ft, 
       total_rolled_tons, 
       chock_usage_cnt, 
       chock_insert_dt, 
       record_modify_dt, 
       next_chock_service_dt_act,
       previous_alarm_value, 
       upload_complete_yn,
       row_number() over (
         partition by chock_id, roll_type
         order by chock_service_dt desc
       ) rn
     from
       tp07_chock_summary_row 
  ) where rn = 1
```

Comment: Oh wow! That did it.  I really apologize for the bad requirements at the beginning. I'm not great with words. Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

```
select color, type, max(date)
from ...
group by color, type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 color,
 type,
 max(date)
from
 yourtable
group by
 color,
 type
```

Comment: Copy/paste your SQL*Plus session here.

Comment: This is what I'm typing

select 
  chock_id, 
  roll_type, 
  max(chock_service_dt), 
  chock_id_dt, 
  chock_seq_num, 
  chock_service_cmnt, 
  total_rolled_lineal_ft, 
  total_rolled_tons, 
  chock_usage_cnt, 
  chock_insert_dt, 
  record_modify_dt, 
  next_chock_service_dt_act,
  previous_alarm_value, 
  upload_complete_yn 
from 
  tp07_chock_summary_row 
group by 
  chock_id, 
  roll_type;

Comment: That does not match what you asked. All non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` list must be referenced in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Okay, I put all of the other columns in Group by.  This gives me data, but it gives me ALL the data.  See above for what I typed in.  This isn't giving me distinct color, type combos.